# Maven Shade plugin not appending all the spring.schemas

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, spring-batch, maven-shade-plugin

I am using a Maven Shade plugin to package all the jars with dependencies into a single jar file. So far I have been successful. The main catch here is that the server on which I am going to run my jar will not be connected to the internet. So I used maven `AppendingTransformer` to append all `spring.schemas` and `spring.handlers` in the process. But still I am unable to find the declaration in spring.schemas for springs batch. I am using springs batch 2.1.7.RELEASE and have the `springs-batch-core` dependency added in `pom.xml` file. Unable to understand the reason behind the same.

Comment: Why are you using the Maven Shade plugin instead of just using Spring Boot?

Comment: Actually the code has already been done and I have just been assigned to find a solution to make it a standalone thing.

Comment: @MichaelMinella The spring boot worked for me.Please make it as an answer so that I can accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using Spring Boot for this type of work these days.  It's really the best way to create Spring applications at this time.